# make new object from another object without change in new one when i changed in old one

Tags: c#, object

I have object `parent`  type of `Border` and I want to make new object `temp` equal to `parent` but I can change in `parent` without change in `temp`

if I write `Border temp = parent`

if I changed anything in `parent` it will change in `temp`

and if I write `Border temp = new border(parent)`

if I changed anything in `parent` it will change in `temp`

this 2 ways are wrong i want it without change in temp

border Class :

```
int x;
        int y;
        string name;
        List<Element> Border_elements;
        Point[] Border_border;
        BorderUnits[,] borderunitsvalue;
        int Numberofunits;
```

borderunits class :

```
bool isempty;
        int currentelementid;
        int x;
        int y;
        List<int> visitedelementsid;
```

Comment: You need to _[clone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx)_ the object

Answer (score 1):

You need to clone parent as temp.

There are a couple of ways to do this:

1) Make a shallow copy by using [MemberwiseClone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx)

```
public Border Clone()
{
   return (Border)this.MemberwiseClone();
}
```

2) Perform a deep copy by serializing the object and then deserialzing it to a new instance. We use the following method for this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This method clones all of the items and serializable properties of the current collection by 
    /// serializing the current object to memory, then deserializing it as a new object. This will 
    /// ensure that all references are cleaned up.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    public static T CreateSerializedCopy<T>(T oRecordToCopy)
    {
        // Exceptions are handled by the caller

        if (oRecordToCopy == null)
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        if (!oRecordToCopy.GetType().IsSerializable)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(oRecordToCopy.GetType().ToString() + " is not serializable");
        }

        System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter oFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();

        using (System.IO.MemoryStream oStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            oFormatter.Serialize(oStream, oRecordToCopy);
            oStream.Position = 0;
            return (T)(oFormatter.Deserialize(oStream));
        }
    }
```

which can be called as:

```
public Border Clone()
{
   return CreateSerializedCopy<Border>(this);
}
```

Comment: my object has un serializable properties so second way are not allowed
first way still change in temp object !!

Answer (score 0):

you want to take a clone or copy the object.

in C#,  when you assign a variable to an object,  you just reference the object.  that variable isn't the object itself.    When you assign a variable to another variable, you just end up with two variables referring to the same object.

Only way to get one object to be the same as another is to make a new object and copy all the state of the other object.      You do this with things like MemberwiseClone, Copy methods, assigning variables yourself.

( Note structs are different )